# Remove overlapping dots from chart

Tags: d3.js

Working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kick_out/njerfb49/

I have a working scatterplot that when you select a letter from the dropdown, the dots with the selected letter in their name will change color and size; but I can't seem to figure out how to remove the old dots (or just write completely over the old dots) so they don't overlap with the selected dots.

```
var changeSelectedColor = function(selPop){
    d3.selectAll('circle')
        .transition().duration(1500)
        .attr("cx",d => xScale(xData(d)))
        .attr("cy",d => yScale(yData(d)))
        .style("fill",'black')
        .attr("r",3.5)
    d3.selectAll('circle.selected')
        .transition().duration(1500)
        .attr("cx",d => xScale(xData(d)))
        .attr("cy",d => yScale(yData(d)))
        .style('fill','orange')
        .attr("r",10)
        .style('opacity',100)
}
```

I've tried several iterations of exit().remove() to no avail. Note when the dropdown item is changed, I change a class attribute on the selected dots to 'selected'. The relevant re-draw function is line 87 (Yes i may have done the re-drawing incorrectly; I am open to different enter().append() or .join() suggestions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main change you want to make is to filter the `selection` before updating, rather than filtering the `data`:

```
dots.filter(d => d.Types.includes(sel)).attr("class",'selected')
```

I also think adding a `"not-selected"` class (before overwriting the selected class as above) will make it easier to update the two classes of points:

```
dots.attr('class', 'not-selected')
```

Finally, I added made sure to reset the opacity of non-selected points. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/x2ocLg6m/).

Comment: It worked. Don't know why I tried using .classed() instead of generic .attr()